# play project run offline

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

All.

I have a play framework project.

I want to run the project on a computer without an Internet connection. I get an errors:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4
.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.feth#play-authenticate_2.11;0.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1: not found
```

Despite the fact that these dependency have a folder ivy2/cashe

how to specify that they must be obtained from ivy cashe?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in sbt, and we're pretty much stuck with it until sbt 0.13.9 (hopefully) fixes it.

It's very, very annoying.

You can see a further discussion on the [Play group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/guice-assistedinject/play-framework/m5iiPwg4uPc/OzJJ_LB5AQAJ).